# Does this phase 'books for thinking' make sense to you?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I want to convey the idea of which I am selling books for people to think deeply, therefore, in short, I want to say 'books for thinking', but when I google it, there is no such phase, I am concerned that it doesn't make sense to native speakers. Actually, I found someone said 'book on thinking'.

Comment: I am not prepared to do the research on this, but as a slogan watcher, I see X for ING all the time. Music for studying, though, is one.

Comment: I think you have to be careful with google. Not everything is already "out there" especially in advertising. One tries to do something others have not yet done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slogan or title like that isn't expected to be a complete, grammatically correct sentence. I know what you mean. I presume most people would know what you mean. So it's perfectly good and valid.

"Book on thinking" would be a very different thing. I'd understand that to mean a book about how the mind works. In once sense or another: I'd imagine it could be anything from a book about the physics and chemistry of the brain to a philosophical discussion about the nature of the mind.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead

> Books for (Deep) **Thinkers**

It's not an especially elegant turn of phrase, but it is [frequently used](https://www.google.com/search?q=books%20for%20thinkers&oq=books%20for%20thinkers&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3847j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

For some reason the noun for the *person* has come to sound better than the gerund for the *activity*.  Likely, this is because *thinking* is itself not particularly special, since everyone regularly *thinks*.  This undermines your intention to describe the process of thinking *interesting* or *unusual* thoughts.

In contrast, a *thinker* is [by definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/thinker), someone who spends a lot of time thinking about deep or significant things, or someone with demonstrated intellectual prowess.

If you really want to focus on the process of thinking, then it might be better to use a more grandiose word, for example:

> Books on **Cogitation**

Comment: I dunno. Books for deep thinkers seem to exclude everyone else.

Comment: @Lambie  I suspect that's the point.

Answer (score 0):

I think "books on thinking" would refer to a book *about* thinking, while "books for thinking" would be closer to what you want. However, with "books for thinking," it's unclear if the reader ends up thinking more about the book itself, or if the book encourages the reader to think more about life itself.

I don't know how formal you want to get, but you might consider: *Books to promote deeper thinking*.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to describe books that make people think, I think the word you're looking for is **encourage**.

```
To help or stimulate (an activity, state, or view) to develop.
```

To give an example:

```
These are books that encourage deep thinking
```

I also like J.R's answer, and use of the word 'promote'